# How can you take long exposure shots with the Sony HX 20V?

Tags: long-exposure, sony, compact-cameras

Is that possible? If so, appreciate if you can explain how it is done.

Comment: DPReview has a [review on your Sony](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/sony-cybershot-dsc-HX20v/2). It says there that the longest exposure time is 30 seconds, and that indeed counts as a "long exposure shot". Might be a good idea to read the manual that came with the camera.

Comment: Thanks Esa, but I didn't found any such detail in the User Manual. Could you please give me some detail/setting(EV, ISO, Shutter speed) under which the digicam will be forced to take a long exposure shot.

Comment: Turn the mode dial to M. That's for Manual exposure mode and you'll be free to set ISO, aperture and shutter speed whichever way you wish. Full manual is a good way to learn, don't hesitate to experiment and remember that camera will not break unless you physically abuse it. Pressing buttons and shooting photos is always safe.

Comment: yup, got that, Will surly try without physically abusing, Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, a long exposure can be done by switching to manual mode and selecting the exposure time (up to 30 sec in your camera). But in order to get a good exposure you also need to set the aperture and ISO. Getting a good long exposure result might be impossible due to the amount of light in the scene and the physical limitations of the camera.

To achieve the longest exposure you want to:

1. Set the lowest ISO (the smallest number - 100 in your camera). This
   will set the "sensitivity" of your sensor to minimum, thus, allowing a
   longer exposure.
2. Set the smallest aperture (the biggest number). This will reduce the
   amount of light coming through the aperture, and again, allow
   a longer exposure.
3. Get a tripod. If you don't have a tripod use a steady surface
   instead. To avoid any further shakes, use the timer mode, this way
   the shakes of the camera caused by your "click" will not affect your
   shot.

After setting these parameters, you can set the exposure time. As I already said, if you shot in the middle of the day, the exposure time will probably be too short to define as "long exposure". The solution to this is using a ND filter. ND stands for Neutral Density - it reduces the amount of light coming through, thus, enabling a longer exposure.

I suggest trying some long exposures at night or in low light scenes.